# VS Code is not recognizing 'nmap'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

I am trying to make a nmap scanner for the InfoSec Certification on freeCodeCamp.org and cannot get Visual Studio Code to recognize that I have installed nmap. I am very beginner and in the process of learning.

```html
from cProfile import run
import nmap

scanner = nmap.PortScanner()

print("Welcome, this is a simple automattion tool")
print("<------------------------------------------->")
```

When I run this in VS Code I get the following in the terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\mjame\OneDrive\Documents\Jim\Coding\fcc_python_for-pen_testing\nmap_scanner_1> python3 scanner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mjame\OneDrive\Documents\Jim\Coding\fcc_python_for-pen_testing\nmap_scanner_1\scanner.py", line 2, in <module>
    import nmap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nmap'
PS C:\Users\mjame\OneDrive\Documents\Jim\Coding\fcc_python_for-pen_testing\nmap_scanner_1>
```

I have so far:

1. Updated to the current Python 3.10.7
2. Installed Nmap the first time from https://nmap.org/ for Windows
3. Uninstalled Nmap
4. Reinsalled Nmap using `>>>pip3 install python-nmap`

Comment: 1. The `PS` at the beginning of your output suggests this is a powershell terminal, as opposed to a standard `cmd` terminal (not sure if this makes any difference).
2. does `python3 -m pip install python-nmap` help at all?

Comment: I used the "python3 -m pip install python-nmap" in the powershell and that fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future searchers (as in my comment above), if you installed a module with `pip3` but are still getting module import errors, try `python3 -m pip install <module-name>`.

Not sure how/why this happens (`pip3` installing somewhere that `python3` is not looking for modules - maybe `PYTHONPATH`-related), but the above can [usually] help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Python cannot find `nmap` module.

You can either add it to path in Windows via Start -> Edit system environment variables -> Environment variables... and then edit `PATH VARIABLE` by adding at the end **path to nmap module** that you have installed or move the module to default Python modules directory which should be `C:\Users\YourLogin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages`